# Jquery string not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, frontend, backend

I have this variable called "questionList", which is an array of objects, in which I have several strings (lets say they are called answer1, answer2...) that it's been passed from the backend to the frontend. In the actual jsp, I want to visualize the strings that are stored each of the object by using a counter, something like this lets say:

```
Not working -> $("#main").html("<c:set var="answer1" scope="page" value="${questionList[count].answer1}"/>");
```

Problem is that when I try to use it the strings are not been displayed in the frontend. However, if I instead of using a counter I use an integer it works perfectly, but of course this is not the correct way to do it.

```
Working -> $("#main").html("<c:set var="answer1" scope="page" value="${questionList[0].answer1}"/>");
```

Any idea of why this ain't working at all using a counter ? And a possible way to actually fix the issue ?

Comment: How do you change the `count` value ?

Comment: Is `count` a variable related to the preprocessor (`<c>`), or to javascript?  The preprocessor would not have access to javascript variables

Comment: Combining `<c:set >` with `$("...").html("...")` won't work that way; `<c:set>` works server-side, while the other works client side.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK if that preprocessor command generates a valid string in quotes, it will work fine.

Comment: The index of the last value in an array of length `count` is `count-1` and not `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that `count` variable has an integer type? If you parse it from the page like attribute or smth like that, you might to use `parseInt(var)`